# Vimeo Search API implementation for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am in a process to develop an app in which the user would enter some text into the textbox . On click of search button , the application fetches list of all videos with details like link , thumbnail and title related to the input. Just like we do in youtube.
I want to bind that data to listbox .

My problem is I am unable to start with it. I have registered my app but do I need client Key and all because I am accessing public videos.
Any help would be appreciated

PS: I am able to do this with youtube. I want JSON data which I can bind.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an unauthenticated token, and use it forever (it will not expire).

There is additional documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#unauthenticated-requests

Comment: I did it !! I want to send the request ! I am unfamiliar about the code ! How to send request using HTTPClient or HTTPWebResponse .

Comment: Would you be able to provide me the url for sending unauthenticated requests? I want to search the Vimeo using a keyword. So If I enter "Microsoft" in my textbox and call Vimeo API , it should fetch all the videos with the title Microsoft !! please do hide your token .

Comment: You make requests by passing the token through the "Authorization" header like this: "Authorization: bearer {token}". Search docs are here: https://developer.vimeo.dev/api/endpoints/videos#